# Custom Expandablelistview adding 2nd child to be shown next to child1

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a Expandablelistview inside a TabFragment which is working fine but I am struggling to **add** *a 2nd child (lblListValue)* next to the 1st child (lblListItem).

*The 2nd childitem also needs to be filled through a HashMap*, I already scouted StackOverflow and the internet to gather some ideas but somehow I cannot find something usefull. I always get stuck in the ExpandableListAdapter code, so I am trying from scratch again.

Some help with this is very welcome.

**Edit:** actually the answer from Frank N. Stein is correct, the LinearLayout should be removed.

list_item.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   android:orientation="vertical" >
>   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
>         android:paddingTop="5sp"
>         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="man1"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" >
>     </TextView>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/lblListValue" <--- 2nd child to be displayed
>         android:paddingTop="5sp"
>         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>         android:paddingRight="20sp"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="right"
>         android:text="test1"
>         android:textSize="14sp">
>     </TextView>      
>   </RelativeLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

TabFragment:

> ```
> public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
>
> ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
> ExpandableListView expListView;
> List<String> listDataHeader;
> HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
> View rootView;
>
> public TabFragment1() {
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
>
>     return rootView;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
>
>     // get the listview
>     expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expListView);
>
>     // preparing list data
>     prepareListData();
>
>     listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
>
>     // setting list adapter
>     expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
>
>     // Listview on child click listener
>     expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
>                                     int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
>             Toast.makeText(
>                     getActivity(),
>                     listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
>                             + " : "
>                             + listDataChild.get(
>                             listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
>                             childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
>                     .show();
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> /*   * Preparing the list data   */
> private void prepareListData() {
>     listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
>     listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
>
>     // Adding child data
>     listDataHeader.add("Factuurgegevens");
>     listDataHeader.add("Contactgegevens");
>     listDataHeader.add("Betalingsgegevens");
>     listDataHeader.add("Mijn account");
>     listDataHeader.add("Wachtwoord");
>
>     // Adding child data
>     List<String> Factuurgegevens = new ArrayList<String>();
>     Factuurgegevens.add("Naam");
>     Factuurgegevens.add("Straat en huisnummer");
>     Factuurgegevens.add("Postcode en woonplaats");
>
>     List<String> Contactgegevens = new ArrayList<String>();
>     Contactgegevens.add("Telefoonummer");
>     Contactgegevens.add("E-mail");
>
>     List<String> Betalingsgegevens = new ArrayList<String>();
>     Betalingsgegevens.add("Rekeningnummer");
>     Betalingsgegevens.add("Naam rekeninghouder");
>
>     List<String> Mijn_account = new ArrayList<String>();
>     Mijn_account.add("Gebruikersnaam");
>
>     List<String> Wachtwoord = new ArrayList<String>();
>     Wachtwoord.add("Wachtwoord");
>
>     listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Factuurgegevens); // Header, Child data
>     listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Contactgegevens);
>     listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Betalingsgegevens);
>     listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Mijn_account);
>     listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Wachtwoord);
> }
> }
> ```

ExpandableListAdapter:

> ```
> public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
>
> private Context _context;
> private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
> // child data in format of header title, child title
> private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
>
> //private final LayoutInflater inf;
>
> public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
>                              HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
>     this._context = context;
>     this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
>     this._listDataChild = listChildData;
>
>     //inf = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.mContext);
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getGroupCount() {
>     return this._listDataHeader.size();
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
>     return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
>             .size();
> }
>
> @Override
> public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
>     return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
> }
>
> @Override
> public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
>     return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
>             .get(childPosititon);
> }
>
> @Override
> public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
>     return groupPosition;
> }
>
> @Override
> public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
>     return childPosition;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean hasStableIds() {
>     return false;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
>                          boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>
>     final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
>
>     if (convertView == null) {
>         LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
>                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>         convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
>     }
>
>     TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
>             .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
>
>     txtListChild.setText(childText);
>     return convertView;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
>                          View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
>     if (convertView == null) {
>         LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
>                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>         convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
>     }
>
>     TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
>             .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
>     lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
>     lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
>
>     return convertView;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
>     return true;
> } 
> }
> ```

Comment: You`re right Frank N. Stein, it`s not nessecary, code adapted.

Comment: ... Now your code looks like my answer!

Comment: Thx  Frank N. Stein for the correction of the layout but that doesn`t answer my question. I wanna add the 2nd chilitem (lblListValue) and fill it also with a HashMap and make it visible. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It would be part of the same row (same child, 2 columns), as shown in my layout.

Comment: I can make a 2nd hashmap for the 2nd child but how to connect it to throught the expandablebaseadapter code wise, that`s my headake.

Comment: Do you want 2 children on the same line?! Why? This is not how ExpandableListViews are supposed to work.

Comment: It`s my first ExpandableListView appologies, how should it be done then?

Comment: When you expand a group (header) in the "main" list, you make another query to retrieve all the records which belong to that parent. This opens the group and shows its children (one per line), much like a ListView inside a ListView. Children (but parents as well) can be composite and show one or more fields. Here's a great [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview)

Comment: Already saw that example, thx for the pointing but that`s not the way I want it. 2nd child should be displayed on the same line alliged to the right.
I appreciate your help anyhow.

Comment: Then you don't want to use an ExpandableListView. Not a standard one, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my version of list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="man1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListValue"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lblListItem"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your answer is actually correct so I accepted and put a edit in the question.